# How to clear 'Apply and Clear' Formatting of a Table in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

After inserting a Table into Excel, I want to change the Table Style.  However, it's not changing the style.
How do I use the 'Apply and Clear Formatting' function in VBA?

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    With ws
        If .Index <> 1 Then

'Insert Table with the Data starting in Column A, Row 3
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Set myTable = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)), , xlYes)

    With myTable
        .Name = .Name & "_Table"
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium12"
        .Range.Font.Bold = True
        .Range.Font.Size = 16
    End With
```

Comment: When I try your code the table has 1048576 rows. Does your code actually create a table for you?

Comment: It does. This code is part of a Loop that will Insert a Table in every Worksheet. Every Worksheet is the same format (Data begins in A3:L).  I reference `.Range("A3").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)` because Column A will always have data to the bottom of the Table.          Everything changes except the actual `TableStyle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, a cell is defined by its coordinates, like A3. The corresponding VBA syntax is `Cells(3, "A")` or better still, `Cells(3, 1)`.

In Excel, a range is defined by its first and last cell, like A3:D12. In VBA the same is expressed like `Range(Cells(3, "A"), Cells(12, "D"))` or - more proficient - `Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(12, 4))`. Prefer numbers to define columns because they can be calculated. Excel can find `Columns(3 + 4)` but it can't find `Columns("C" + 4)`.

`Cells(Rows.Count, "A")` defines a single cell which is equal to `Cells(1048576, 1)`. It's the last possible cell in column A. Similarly, `Cells(3, Columns.Count)` defines a cell at the extreme right of row 3. `Columns.Count` = 16384 but might be a smaller number in worksheets created with earlier versions of Excel.

The combination of either of the above expressions with `.End(xlUp)` or `End.(xlToLeft)` just describes an offset from the cell already defined, to look for the first occupied cell (the *End*), either *up* or *To[the]Left*. Therefore these expressions define a single cell. They wouldn't even define a range if they were presented as first and last cell of a range in proper syntax. This, `Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))`, isn't proper syntax.

In the code below I have taken pains to take you through the process of defining the range for your table in small steps. It works, and that's great. But the point is that it should work for you, and it will only do that if you fully understand it. I hope the above explanation helps toward that end.

```
Sub InsertTable()
    ' 026

    Dim Ws      As Worksheet
    Dim Tbl     As ListObject
    Dim Rng     As Range                ' range in which to set the table
    Dim Rl      As Long                 ' last row
    Dim Cl      As Long                 ' last column

    For Each Ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With Ws
            If .Index > 1 Then
                ' find the last used row in column A
                Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                ' find the last used column in row 3
                Cl = .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                ' set the range for the table
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, "A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))
                ' convert the range to a table
                Set Tbl = .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Rng, , xlYes)
            End If
        End With

        With Tbl
            .Name = .Name & "_Table"
            .TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium12"
            .Range.Font.Bold = True
            .Range.Font.Size = 16
        End With
    Next Ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to type this all out! I do have a couple of questions. With your notation that VBA prefers numbers, should I then set the Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row? and Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(Rl, Cl))?

Comment: I do have more after the table formatting, and I'm trying to avoid the .Select and .Active.. So, should I move the End With for the With Ws and the Next Ws at the end of the Sub?

Comment: I typed in the above syntax (exactly as it is), everything after the `With Tbl` did not change. I changed the `If .Index > 1 Then` to `If .Index <> 1 Then`, and moved the `End With` (for the `With Ws`) and `Next Ws` to after the `With Tbl` / `End With`, and the `Font.Bold` / `Font.Size` worked, but the Table did not change colors.

Comment: Further on into the macro, I insert a formula and want to `.Autofill` down a column, referencing Column A as the Last Row of Data.  I was using: `DataLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` / `.Range("F4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F4:F" & DataLastRow)`.   Should I change this to: `DataLastRow = .Range("A"), .Cells(Rl, Cl))` `.Range("F4").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("F4:F" & DataLastRow)`?

Comment: Saying "Excel prefers numbers" I referred to column numbers as opposed to column names. If you move End With (Ws) to the end of the sub then With Tbl will become nested within With Ws. Not good practice. The smallest index number of a collection is always 1. Maybe the color you try to set is the default or not available. Try another. The code worked for me. Excel will Autofill formulas within a table automatically. It's not so simple. I prefer you to launch another question about that.

Comment: Ok.. but if I leave the `End With (Ws)` after creating the table, how to I move to the next Ws to complete the rest macro?  This code created the table through all Worksheets, but the `With Tbl` then stops on Sheet2.

Comment: Aah! You are right. I was confused. Yes. The `Next Ws` must move to the end. In fact, I now moved it there in my above code.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, the table still does not change colors.  I need to figure out how to clear the formatting as if I go into Table Tools - Design - (Right Click) on a Table Style - Apply and Clear Formatting

Comment: Your code works for me. Therefore I can't replicate the error and can't find a cure for it. Since it isn't in the code, the problem must be either in the table or the style. You might try and repair Excel, on the assumption that it produces a corrupt table or has a corrupted style. As an other off-thought: remove conditional formatting there might be in the range in the range - anything that might make your range different from the one I tried your code on.